# booting ubuntu on a imx6 board from scratch

Tags: compiling

I am interested in booting up the ubuntu on a imx6  duallite based board  using uboot, since i am a beginner ,please suggest some guidelines for the this.

I am also interested to create with my own root file system,which can be used on the same board.

Please suggest me how can achieve the same

Comment: You are trying to boot Ubuntu ans not just generic Linux kernel right? This may help http://boundarydevices.com/trusty-ubuntu-mx6/